# MIDP in Java ME SDK 8.1

Tags: sdk, java-me, midp

I have a CLDC 1.1 / MIDP 2.0 project which compiled fine with Java ME SDK 3.2.

Recently I have upgraded my Java SE to 8 and as a result the Java ME SDK started displaying errors on Windows startup (saying that Java version is 8 while 7 is expected).

So I upgraded my Java ME SDK to 8.1. My problem is that it doesn't contain midp_2.0.jar so I don't know how to compile my project. The compiler displays errors such as:

```
package javax.microedition.lcdui does not exist
```

What should I install to compile my MIDP project?

Comment: Oracle Java ME 8.1 is targeted towards embedded uses only, and so, do not come with a MIDP profile implementation (no LCDUI). However, it provides an implementation of the MEEP profile, which is an evolution of IMP-NG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by installing Java ME SDK 3.4. It is compatible with Java SE 8.